# Java/Android: generic method - apply same functionality to different objects

Tags: java, android, generics

I am trying to make some helper method in my Android project - method to set background with outline. I would like to method accepts different types of object (minimum is different Layouts) and call setBackground() on them. My code:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static <I> void setBackgroundOutlined(Context context, 
                                                I item, 
                                                String backgroundColor, 
                                                String outlineColor, int outlineThickness,
                                                Boolean setStatesPressed) {


    GradientDrawable shapeDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
    shapeDrawable.setStroke(CF.floatToPixels(context, outlineThickness), 
    Color.parseColor(outlineColor));
    shapeDrawable.setColor(Color.parseColor(backgroundColor));


    StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();

    states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed, 
    android.R.attr.state_enabled}, 
    context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.textview_pressed_color));
    states.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, shapeDrawable);


    if (item instanceof RelativeLayoutWithContextMenuInfo) {

        RelativeLayoutWithContextMenuInfo item2= (RelativeLayoutWithContextMenuInfo)item;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            item2.setBackgroundDrawable(states);
        } else {
            item2.setBackground(states);
        }

    } else if (item instanceof LinearLayout) {

        LinearLayout item2= (LinearLayout)item;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            item2.setBackgroundDrawable(states);
        } else {
            item2.setBackground(states);
        }

    }




}
```

I really dislike repeating code in condiditons. Any suggestion to make it more clearly? Thanks, J.

Answer (score 2):

addition to *jacobhyphenated* answer :

You don't need a generic method as you would only need to pass a parameter of  `ViewGroup` type or its subclasses :

```
private static void setBackgroundOutlined(Context context, 

 /* you can pass any layout as item -> */ ViewGroup item, 
                                          String backgroundColor, 
                                          String outlineColor,
                                          int outlineThickness,
                                          Boolean setStatesPressed) {

    // apply you logic on a item based on OS runtime API
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `setBackgroundDrawable` and `setBackground` methods exist in the `ViewGroup` class. You can enforce that any `item` must be or extend `ViewGroup` in your generic.

```
private static <I extends ViewGroup> void setBackgroundOutlined(Context context, 
                                            I item, 
                                            String backgroundColor, 
                                            String outlineColor, int outlineThickness,
                                            Boolean setStatesPressed) {

        ....

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            item.setBackgroundDrawable(states);
        } else {
            item.setBackground(states);
        }

}
```

But this will only work if you are always using the `ViewGroup` parent class.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't make it as generic as it is now, since you're trying to do something quite specific, still.
You'd better be off swapping `I` to `ViewGroup` or `View` (although this might be too vague, still), or something like that.

It's not very generic to check for the object type in generic code, but using the right superclass for the objects you're trying to support (such that this superclass contains the methods you intent to call on the object) is a better approach.